# branch.io deeplink sometimes doesn't redirect to the Appstore on messenger on iOS

Tags: reactjs, deep-linking, facebook-messenger, branch.io

Redirection to the appstore from a deeplink works randomly on facebook messenger, only on ios.
After clicking the link, when the prompt pops up asking if the user wants to leave Messenger and open another app, pressing Continue will often leads to nowhere, leaving the user stuck on the https://[my.domain].link.

The times it will work, it always pops up the prompt 2 times asking to leave Messenger when it is working. The first prompt never works, only the second one does.
This behavior will happen randomly for the same link.

I have tried tweaking the $uri_redirect_mode parameter, unsuccessfully

The parameters I'm passing to the link are ase simple as follows :

```
'$uri_redirect_mode': 1,
'$canonical_identifier': canonicalIdentifier,
'$desktop_url': 'https://itunes.apple.com/fr/app/myApp/appId',
'$ios_url': 'https://itunes.apple.com/fr/app/myApp/appId',
'$android_url': 'https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.myApp'
```

I expect the branch deep link to work in a more consistent way on facebook messenger, knowing that I don't have this problem on whatsapp (ios) or android. Please help me understand if I'm missing something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Branch Links are known to resolve to your fallbacks on FB messenger regardless if you have the app installed or not. For Branch Links shared on IOS Facebook Messenger, you should enable a deep view as an intermediate step between your redirect.

Reference: https://docs.branch.io/links/integrate/#expected-link-behavior

If you have additional questions, please write in to support@branch.io. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've already read the documention but I don't understand how to fix my problem. I contacted branch support.
Thanks again !